# In Perl, how can I convert all newlines to spaces in a string?

Tags: perl, string

Are there any functions are available for converting all newlines in a string to spaces?

For example:

```
$a = "dflsdgjsdg
dsfsd 
gf 
sgd 
g  
sdg
sdf
gsd";
```

The result is am looking for is:

```
$a = "dflsdgjsdg dsfsd gf sgd g sdg sdf gsd"
```

Comment: is there anything for wrong in questions for down vote ?

Comment: I asked this question i thought s// will be more time . thats y i asked .is there any other way of doing

Comment: Although they aren't strictly reserved or locked, you should avoid using `$a` and `$b` as ordinary variables in Perl. They're automatically used by Perl's `sort` function, so it's best to leave them alone otherwise.

Comment: +1 This question is basic. There are answers giving several possible solutions. There are explanations why one may be better than the others. An answer with the best performance without any obfuscation has floated to the top by up votes. Having the question and answers here helps to fulfill this: "finding the right answer to your programming questions should be as easy as falling into the pit of success", from the SO About page.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would recommend restricting the use of `$a` and `$b` to sort routines only.

For your question, `tr///` is more appropriate than `s///`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $x = q{dflsdgjsdg
dsfsd
gf
sgd
g
sdg
sdf
gsd};

$x =~ tr{\n}{ };

print $x, "\n";
__END__
```

Output:

```
C:\Temp> ttt
dflsdgjsdg dsfsd gf sgd g sdg sdf gsd
```

**Update:** I do not think TMTOWTDI justifies using anything other than `tr///` here. First, semantically, what the OP is asking for is *transliteration* and therefore it makes sense to use transliteration. Second, at least on my Windows XP laptop with 5.10, the benchmark module provides a clear contrast:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Benchmark qw( cmpthese );

use constant LONG_STRING => "\n" x 1_000_000;

cmpthese -10, {
    subst => sub {
        my $x = LONG_STRING;
        $x =~ s{\n}{ }g;
        return;
    },
    split_join => sub {
        my $x = LONG_STRING;
        $x = join ' ', split /\n/, $x;
        return;
    },
    tr => sub {
        my $x = LONG_STRING;
        $x =~ tr{\n}{ };
        return;
    },
    nop => sub {
        my $x = LONG_STRING;
        return;
    }
};
__END__
```

Results:

```
              Rate split_join      subst         tr        nop
split_join 0.354/s         --       -85%      -100%      -100%
subst       2.40/s       578%         --       -99%      -100%
tr           250/s     70514%     10320%         --       -92%
nop         3025/s    854076%    125942%      1110%         --
```

**One more update:** I should point out that the relative performance of `tr///` to `s///` depends on the size and composition of the source string. The case I chose for illustration here is definitely extreme. Using less extreme input strings, the performance ratio seems to be closer to `15:1` rather than `100:1` ;-)

Comment: It's a good idea to avoid $a and $b outside of sort. Since the OP might not know _why_ those variables are special, I added a comment to his original question saying why (briefly).

Answer (score 8):

Try the following program:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $a = 'dflsdgjsdg
dsfsd
gf
sgd
g
sdg
sdf
gsd';
$a =~ s{\n}{ }g;

print $a;
```

The program simply uses a regular expression to search for newlines and replace them with spaces globally.

Comment: is the substitution is faster than other functions ?

Comment: Why don't you try it and find out?

Comment: for my operation substitution is faster

Comment: I think you need to use the `s` modifier to treat the string as a multi-line string.

Answer (score 4):

how about substitition

```
$a = "dflsdgjsdg
dsfsd 
gf 
sgd 
g  
sdg
sdf
gsd";

$a =~ s/\n/ /g;
print $a;
```

or using split and join

```
@s =split /\n/,$a;
print join(" ",@s);
```

Comment: which one is faster substitution or split&join ?

Comment: i haven't time it, but you can try for yourself using Benchmark module

Comment: for my string substitution is faster

Answer (score 3):

This is a nice question because it embodies Perl's [TMTOWTDI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There%27s_more_than_one_way_to_do_it).

The answers above give 3 options, all of which are valid.  I'll summarize them here.

The string is:

```
$a = "dflsdgjsdg
dsfsd 
gf 
sgd 
g  
sdg
sdf
gsd";
```

### substitution

```
$a =~ s/\n/ /g;
```

### transliteration

```
$a =~ tr/\n/ /;
```

### split/join

```
$a = join " ", split "\n", $a;
```